# TrayIcon balloon does not show up

Tags: c++, system-tray, systray, trayicon, balloon

I compiled my trayicon utility c++ code in visual studio 2005 express edition and tray icon balloons showed up successfully but later I deleted my firewall, switched on to windows firewall and now I am on another firewall software. Now i ran my same project and balloons showed up successfully but when i rebuilt it, i can't see balloons anymore. My Shell_NotifyIcon method still returns true.

Here is the code:

```
nid.cbSize              = sizeof( NOTIFYICONDATA_V2_SIZE ); // i've tested NOTIFYICONDATA   //and nid as well

nid.hWnd                = hWnd;
nid.uID                 = uID;
nid.uFlags              = NIF_ICON | NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_TIP|NIF_INFO;
nid.dwInfoFlags         = 0x00000004;
strcpy(nid.szInfoTitle  , balloonTitle);
strcpy(nid.szInfo       , balloonMsg);
int ret = Shell_NotifyIcon( NIM_MODIFY, &nid );
```

Can anybody suggest where does the problem lie? it seems it is related to OS, my OS is XP and i've even modified "EnableBalloonTips" to 1.

Faran Shabbir

Comment: anyone............. please???

Comment: Ok I figured it out myself. 
nid.cbSize = sizeof( NOTIFYICONDATA_V2_SIZE );  
should be 
nid.cbSize = NOTIFYICONDATA_V2_SIZE;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I figured it out myself. `nid.cbSize = sizeof( NOTIFYICONDATA_V2_SIZE );` should be `nid.cbSize = NOTIFYICONDATA_V2_SIZE;`